# CentOS 8 network on boot

Tags: networking, centos, boot

I'm running CentOS 8, every time I reboot the network does not start until I log in to the system.

I've checked the NetworkManager and the autoconnect is set to yes.

```
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
```

In network-scripts/ifcfg-ens192 the followings settings are

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=ens192
UUID=0b36cba5-01ed-4c38-a373-1a928301b982
DEVICE=ens192
ONBOOT=yes
```

Is there a way for the network to start on boot instead having to log in?

Comment: Do you have the right interface name? `ens192` is rather unexpected.

Comment: Yes, CentOS is virtualised.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, I used this command:

```
nm-connection-editor
```

And changed some settings which I thought needed changing, I think this one did the job:

```
All users may connect to this network
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

It was solved by Toggle on the option "Available to all users" in `nmtui`.

or

Delete the `USER=root` in the `network-scripts/ifcfg-ens*`

but I did not see `USER=root` in your `network-scripts/ifcfg-ens192`.